# Arc Length of a sinusoid wrapped around a circle

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry

I am trying to find the length of the arc defined by these equations:

$x = (R + a\sin(n\theta))\cos(\theta)$

$y = (R + a\sin(n\theta))\sin(\theta)$,

where $R =$ circle radius, $a =$ sinusoid amplitude.

Using this formula:

$Arc = \int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{x^\prime(\theta)^2 + y^\prime(\theta)^2}\,\mathrm d\theta$

And I get to this integral (which I cant solve):

$\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{ (R + a\sin(n\theta))^2 + (an\cos(n\theta))^2 }\,\mathrm d\theta$

Any help would be much appreciated. This is my first post.

Comment: Nice question! Write your equations between a pair of dollar signs \$ \$.

Comment: What is $n$? Anyway, starting with substitution $u=n\theta$ seems like a good first step to me.

Comment: I think this can be written in form of the Elliptic integral for certain values of $R$, $a$ and $n$. But I don't think a general form exists.